# GCP storage Can't upload string with invisible ascii caracters

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-storage

I'm using python3.6

When I try to upload a file with non visible ascii caracters I have an error from gcp.

```
import tempfile
from google.cloud import storage
client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket('my-bucket')
blob = bucket.blob('test_ascii')
fd = tempfile.TemporaryFile('w+')
fd.write('\u0090')
fd.seek(0)
blob.upload_from_file(fd)
```

I get the following exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 1085, in upload_from_file
    client, file_obj, content_type, size, num_retries, predefined_acl
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 995, in _do_upload
    client, stream, content_type, size, num_retries, predefined_acl
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 942, in _do_resumable_upload
    response = upload.transmit_next_chunk(transport)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/resumable_media/requests/upload.py", line 396, in transmit_next_chunk
    self._process_response(result, len(payload))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/resumable_media/_upload.py", line 574, in _process_response
    self._get_status_code, callback=self._make_invalid)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/resumable_media/_helpers.py", line 93, in require_status_code
    status_code, u'Expected one of', *status_codes)
google.resumable_media.common.InvalidResponse: ('Request failed with status code', 400, 'Expected one of', <HTTPStatus.OK: 200>, 308)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 1089, in upload_from_file
    _raise_from_invalid_response(exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 1960, in _raise_from_invalid_response
    raise exceptions.from_http_status(response.status_code, message, response=response)
google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 PUT https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/my-bucket/o?uploadType=resumable&upload_id=AEnB2Uo0YkAqrWxqv4zVpm7bsO1mbUCGNIjxQPrQa4OV5HPad6kQatXYUF0UWVc8rWTMGEoYRIKH-QBUGmd35-u6FLRw04c4-A: ('Request failed with status code', 400, 'Expected one of', <HTTPStatus.OK: 200>, 308)
```

And when I display more information I get the following piece of code
`b'Invalid request.  There were 3 byte(s) in the request body.  There should have been 6 byte(s) (starting at offset 0 and ending at offset 5) according to the Content-Range header.'`

The solution was to open the file in binary mode and then encode the string, but I tought that it was useless to do that on linux.

Am I missing something?  Is it a good practice to always manipulate string as bytes in order to avoid this error, or is it something from gcp ?

Comment: You aren't closing the file before uploading it. If you add:
fd.close();
after the fd.write() call (and delete the fd.seek() calll) do you still get an error?

Comment: I get the following error `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.` and in the doc they don't close the fd before the upload

Comment: I overlooked the fact that you opened the file in w+ mode, which means it can be read as well as written. You're right, you don't need to close the file (and reopen for read) when opened this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that for non-ASCII characters you need to open the file in binary mode.

According to the documentation of the Python Client for Google Cloud Storage, the [`Blob.upload_from_file`](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/_modules/google/cloud/storage/blob.html#Blob.upload_from_file) calls an internal method `Blob._do_upload` which expects the parameter `stream` representing the file object to be:

> `:type stream: IO[bytes]`
>   `:param stream: A bytes IO object open for reading.`